# Mysterious "raison d'être" of filtrations of congruence subgroups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, shimura-varieties, filtrations

I wonder for long why congruence subgroups seem to arise so naturally in **certain** filtrations. Everything below is on a local field $F_p$.

**Filtration for $GL_n$.** [Casselman](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002307618) and later [Jacquet, Piatetski-Shapiro and Shalika](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002320606) established a theory of newforms for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, finding a well-suited filtration capturing the newvectors and the notion of conductor of a representation. It is given by the following sequence of congruence subgroups:

$$K(p^m) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
& & &  \\
& & & \\
p^m & \cdots & p^m & 1+p^m
\end{array}
\right)$$

where $p^m$ is abusively written for the ideal $(p^m) = p^m \mathcal{O}_F$, and empty slots are left for the integer ring, convention I will use also below. Also, it is understood that the group written are meant to be its intersection with the ambient group (invertible matrices in the case above).

So in this case we already get a somewhat particular filtration, for we naively could have chosen the usual congruence subgroups $\Gamma(p^m)$, $\Gamma_0(p^m)$ or $\Gamma_1(p^m)$.

**Filtrations for $U(1,1)$.** [Lansky and Raghuram](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503090.pdf) introduce the following filtrations:
$$K(p^m) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
& \\
p^m &
\end{array}
\right)
\quad 
and \quad 
K'(p^m) = \alpha K(p^m) \alpha^{-1}$$

where $\alpha$ is a well chosen element (such that for $m=0$ we get the two maximal compact subgroups of $U(1,1)$). Here a new feature appears: there is not only one filtration made of particular "congruence" subgroups, but two intertwined such filtrations. Indeed, we can check that $K(p^m)\subset K'(p^m)\subset K(p^{m-1})$.

**Filtration for $U(2,1)$.** [Miyauchi](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1826-02.pdf) introduce, in the quasi-split unitary group in 3 variables setting, the following filtration:
$$K(p^m) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & p^{-m}  \\
p^m & 1+p^m & \\
p^m & p^m &
\end{array}
\right)$$

declared to be "inspired" by the standard filtrations of JPSS above or Robert and Schmidt below. Again a new feature here appear: it is no more a proper "filtration", for it is not a decreasing sequence.

**Filtration for $GSp(4)$.** [Robert and Schmidt](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~rschmidt/papers/NF.pdf) used the so called "paramodular" subgroups:
$$K(p^m) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
& & & p^{-m}  \\
p^m & & & \\
p^m & & & \\
p^m& p^m & p^m & 
\end{array}
\right)$$

The two maximal compact subgroups of $GSp(4)$ appearing as $K(p^0)$ and $K(p^1)$ in this case.

All those examples are disturbing to me. Indeed, they all seem to be very *ad hoc* choices: they don't seem to be build on the same model (of, for instance, an obvious generalization of $\Gamma_0(m)$); they don't have volumes or indices clearly related to the rank or the size of the group; sometimes they are real decreasing filtrations, sometimes not; sometimes they give good "multiplicity one" results sometimes not, etc.

My question is mainly:

> What is happening here?

I am seeking some deeper and more geometrical reasons for considering exactly those filtrations and not others.

Is there something related in one of these directions to justify the choice:

- **algebraic structure of $G$** (for instance the fact that there is one or more maximal compact subgroups, giving rise to a non-decreasing sequence, as in $GSp(4)$ or $SO$ (works of Tsai)
- **Shimura varieties**, those filtrations being those giving good property to the quotient varieties? In the same directions, we could think of **multiplicity or limit multiplicity** properties

At a much more pragmatic level, is there a somehow canonical or systematic way to choosing them? (question which is probably related to the two above)

Comment: Try learning about parahoric subgroups and Moy-Prasad filtrations.  Also, stabilizers of lattices.

Comment: @Kimball, certainly [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280568/mysterious-raison-d%c3%aatre-of-filtrations-of-congruence-subgroups#comment691806_280568) is good advice for more insight into the zoo of filtrations, but it doesn't seem to be the whole answer to the question.  For example, the non-nested Miyauchi 'filtration' definitely isn't an MP filtration, and the I think the JPSS filtration isn't either.